# I wrote a face detection program using DLIBS but every time I run it I get this error

Tags: python, dlib

I have tried downloading shape_68.dat and putting it in the same directory as the program but still not luck. Any ideas on whats causing this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dmsta\PycharmProjects\Face Traking For Laser\main.py", line 39, in 
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_68.dat')
RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_68.dat

Comment: What matters is where you ran the program from.  If you typed, for example, `python "Face Traking For Laser\main.py"`, then the file needs to be in the `PycharmProjects` directory.

Comment: My file is in the same folder as the Main.Py, but I am still getting the error

Comment: I don't think you read what I wrote.  How, exactly, are you running this app?

Comment: I'm just running it in Pycharm. (also sorry if I seem a little confused i'm new to this whole programming thing)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the file I have having the .dat.bz2 extension as opposed to just .dat

Comment: Of course it does.  The file must be called "shape_68.dat".  Do you have a bunzip tool?

Comment: No, will download it online right now, how should I convert the file?. Thanks for bearing with me and helping!

Comment: EIther `bunzip2` or `7zip` can unpack the file out to its original form.  Python has a `bz2` module, but you'd have to write a short program to convert it.